# I am constantly getting 'Run time error 13' with 'mydate = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value'

Tags: excel, error-handling, runtime, vba

As per the following logic, the code hides some rows, however it stops at row 80 and shows this error. I checked for the format of these date and time, looks good to me. 
Can someone help figure what could have gone wrong?

```
Public Sub ShowShift3()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim mydate As Date
Dim mytime As Date
Dim mystatus As String

lastrow1 = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Summary").Activate

For i = lastrow1 To i = 2 Step -1
mydate = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value
mytime = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "B").Value
If (mydate < Date) And (mytime < TimeValue("22:00:00")) Then
   Worksheets("Summary").Rows(i).Hidden = True
End If    
Next    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to replace your code with the following, I believe it should work as expected:

```
Public Sub ShowShift3()
Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long
Dim mydate As Date
Dim mytime As Date
Dim mystatus As String

lastrow1 = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = lastrow1 To 2 Step -1
    If IsDate(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value) = True Then 'check if the contents in the cell are in fact a date
        mydate = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value
        mytime = Format(Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "B").Value, "hh:mm") 'format the time properly for comparison
        If (mydate < Date) And (mytime < TimeValue("22:00:00")) Then
            Worksheets("Summary").Rows(i).Hidden = True
        End If
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @RahulBaranwal also, just a pointer, you don't need to Activate a sheet to work with it, you might have noticed that I removed that line from the code.

Comment: Oh yes! I noticed that. I always get confused as to when do we activate it. Is there a general situation where I need to activate sheet?

Comment: @RahulBaranwal I haven't yet encountered a situation where I had to activate a sheet, there is always a work around (might be wrong) but activating and selecting always make your code slower. Again if this has helped please mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The error may be in your data rather than the code:

```
Sub DateCheck()
    Dim mydate As Date
    i = 1
    mydate = Sheets("Summary").Cells(i, "A").Value
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: That makes sense, Although I checked to see if the cells have the right content, I will do it again to see if I have missed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably VBA cannot parse the value that you have in the corresponding cell to a Date.

Check the following:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim a As Date
    a = "what"
    a = ""
End Sub
```

Both `""` and `"what"` cannot be converted to a Date. I guess that in your case the `Cells(i, "A")` is an empty one, thus you are getting this error.

The other variable types `Long`, `String`, `Variant`, `Object` etc. can be easily assigned to the value of empty cell and each one of them would parse it correspondingly:

- `Long` becomes `0`
- `String` becomes `""`
- `Boolean` becomes `False`

Comment: Yes, I came across this thing in my earlier codes, checked for it, doesn't seem to be this error.